# facebook-node-sdk for node.js scope parameter?

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js, express, facebook-node-sdk

https://github.com/amachang/facebook-node-sdk
decided to use this module to build my facebook integrated login for node.js following the example with express:

```
var express = require('express');
```

var Facebook = require('facebook-node-sdk');

```
var app = express.createServer();
app.configure(function () {
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'foo bar' }));
  app.use(Facebook.middleware({ appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID', secret: 'YOUR_APP_SECRET' }));
});

app.get('/', Facebook.loginRequired(), function (req, res) {
  req.facebook.api('/me', function(err, user) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello, ' + user.name + '!');
  });
});
```

how to add additional permissions  like "email"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the method [getLoginUrl](https://github.com/amachang/facebook-node-sdk/blob/master/lib/basefacebook.js#L347) in the Facebook Node SDK. You can provide a `scope` parameter here to specify the `email` permission. See [Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) for a list of available permissions.

Comment: yeah I looked that ... looks like the only way is to modify this file 
Thanks

Comment: Yeah seems that way, but I'm sure they're open to accepting a revision if you add this feature.

Comment: BTW, if you find this answer helpful, please upvote it and/or accept it so that other people can make use of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
app.get('/', Facebook.loginRequired({scope: 'email'}), function (req, res) {
      /*-----*/
});
```

Comment: Some more context would help this answer.

Answer (score 0):

hmm You don't need to edit this file :) all you have to do is add scope to your config, like this:

```
app.use(Facebook.middleware({ appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID', secret: 'YOUR_APP_SECRET', scope 'YOUR_SCOPE' }))
```

this config is then passed to getLoginUrl function